# Chat mass-unstar script

Tags: script, chat

We from the [Python room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) like to have a clean list of starred messages, so only relevant and really liked messages stay on the starred list forever. In order to do that, we unstar messages from time to time. Since unstarring is limited to the sidebar list within Chat, this is not really a simple thing to do.

That’s where this script comes in: When you visit a room’s star list, you can now select multiple starred messages simply by clicking on them. And if you have made your selection, you can click the *“Unstar all selected messages”* button to unstar them all.

[image: Screenshot of the script in action]

### Install and source

- **[Click to install](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/poke/ab25d627b2c4b02db6b8/raw/stackexchange-chat-mass-unstar.user.js)**
- [Source](https://gist.github.com/poke/ab25d627b2c4b02db6b8)
- Current version: 1.2.0 (2018-02-08 23:20 UTC)

### Changelog

- **1.2.0:** Rewrite with better support for HTTPS and other sites
- **1.1.1:** Add HTTPS support
- **1.1.0:** Expand functionality to chat.SE and chat.meta.SE
- **1.0.1:** Fix: Script not working on star lists that have no paging
- **1.0.0:** Initial release

Comment: I loved it. I used it to clean up [Indian Enthusiastic Programmers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13215/indian-enthusiastic-programmers) room. It doesn't show the button in the last page of the starred list, apart from that it was awesome.

Comment: @thefourtheye Just pushed an update that should fix that issue. And I’m glad it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. We do the same thing in the SOCVR Room and this will make life so much easier.

Comment: Hmm, still not working, I think you need to change the [25th line to https as well](https://gist.github.com/poke/ab25d627b2c4b02db6b8#file-stackexchange-chat-mass-unstar-user-js-L25).